Many to Many Recursive Relationship
I have a database with a single table, with a Many to Many Recursive Relatopnship.
Need to: "Associate/join" records and also be able to delete the joins.
I've know basic sql: insert, delete, update, etc, but I've never had to work with a Many to Many Recursive Relationship.
The following code attempt was copied from an example and then modified by me.
When I run it thru an "sql Checker" i receive many syntax errors, but when I compared what I modified with the orginal code, I feel the my syntax is the same???
Also, how do I code to create and delete this kind of relationship?
Note: The example that I copied from and then modified was a many to many releationship bewteen two tables.
G_Garment(G_Shopper_ID);
G_Garment(Left_G_Shopper_ID, Right_G_Shopper_ID)
FOREIGN KEY (Left_G_Shopper_ID REFERENCES G_Garment(G_Shopper_ID)
FOREIGN KEY (Right_G_Shopper_ID) REFERENCES G_Garment(G_Shopper_ID)
CHECK (Left_G_Shopper_ID <> Right_G_Shopper_ID);
G_Garment(Left_G_Shopper_ID, Right_G_Shopper_ID)
    FOREIGN KEY (Left_G_Shopper_ID) REFERENCES G_Garment(G_Shopper_ID)
    FOREIGN KEY (Right_G_Shopper_ID) REFERENCES G_Garment(G_Shopper_ID);

OR
CREATE TABLE G_Garment (
G_Shopper_ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
FOREIGN KEY (G_Shopper_ID)
REFERENCES G_Garment(G_Shopper_ID)
ON DELETE RiSTRICT
)
